# How I can put this information,"Project"-> "Name", in a textView , Android, using Retrofit 1.9?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

How I can put this information,"Project"-> "Name", in a textView, using Retrofit 1.9?

[Here is a picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfkbv.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this (although you could've googled this yourself):

```
JSONObject obj = json.getJsonObject("Project");
String name = obj.getString("name");
```

This is having in mind that `json` is the variable which holds the json data. Although I'm not quite sure if it's in an array, I cannot see from the picture since it's cut off. You might wanna edit the question with **json response** as a text.